# GeoPoint in Firestore using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save GeoPoint in my Firebase Firestore using Python, and I didn't have any success.
This is giving me syntax error:

```
location=new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
```

Is there any solution for this? Maybe I'm missing something to import, but I can't find what. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

```py
from google.cloud.firestore import GeoPoint

# Just example values so the code runs.
latitude = 0.0
longitude = 0.0
location = GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)

print(location)
```

`new` is not python keyword and needs not to be used.

Comment: For future visitor, you can import firestore as `from google.cloud import firestore` and then do like `location = firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)`.